# Using Scrapy Spider results for a website

Tags: scrapy

I've experimented with some crawlers to pull web data from within a Python environment on my local machine. Ideally, I'd like to host a website that can initiate crawlers to aggregate content and display that on the site.

My question is, is it possible to do this from a web environment and not my local machine?

Answer (score 1):

Sure there are many services that are doing the same task you wanted.
`scrapingHub` is the best example you can get. https://scrapinghub.com/

You can deploy your spiders in there and run it periodically(paid service). Deploy and call spider via `scrapingHub API` form your website and use the spider output in your host website.

Also, you can achieve the same idea in your server and website via API call.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'll investigate these options.